# Alert doesn't work

Tags: php, html, file, upload, alert

I am trying to pop up an alert in a php file if the user hasn't upload a file in input element.

The source code in index.php :

```
<input type='file' name="imgInp" id="imgInp" accept=".jpg, .png, .jpeg|images/*"/>
<img style="max-height: 400px; max-width: 400px;" id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />
```

In submitted php file:

```
if($_FILES["imgInp"]["name"]!='')
{
$first_file=rand().$_FILES["imgInp"]["name"];
$path="images/template/usersupload/";
$tot_dir=$path.$first_file;
    if(file_exists($path))
    {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["imgInp"]["tmp_name"],$tot_dir);
    }
}
else
{
    echo '<script>alert("You forgot to upload a file!!!");
                                             </script>';
                                              echo'<script type="text/javascript">';
                                             ?>
               window.location="index.php";
          <?php
          echo '</script>';

}
```

Comment: There is no _PHP alert_

Comment: @bub he is echoing a js alert

Comment: @litelite I am aware of that, but the title is php alert does not work

Comment: Check the dev console for errors

Comment: It's my first time which i am using PHP, i don't know what is and how i could use the dev console. Can you please provide me more details. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I believe litelite is referring to the [JavaScript console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers)

Answer (score -1):

Change you Submit Php  Code To 
You Forgot To Wrap Alert In Script Tag :)

```
        if($_FILES["imgInp"]["name"]!='')
        {
        $first_file=rand().$_FILES["imgInp"]["name"];
        $path="images/template/usersupload/";
        $tot_dir=$path.$first_file;
            if(file_exists($path))
            {
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["imgInp"]["tmp_name"],$tot_dir);
            }
        }
        else
        {
        echo'<script type="text/javascript">';
            echo '<script>alert("You forgot to upload a file!!!");
    setInterval(function(){window.location.href="index.php" },5000);
    </script>';
                                                        echo '</script>';
 }
                                                     ?>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work even after your edit.